# How do I flush the input buffer correctly after I get the next char without having to press enter twice! C++

Tags: c++, cin

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char input;
    while (1) {
        cout << "Enter: ";
        cin.get(input);
        cin.ignore(100, '\n'); //requires another `enter`
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to get the next character in the input buffer, and I want that input buffer to be cleared afterwards. I know that we can use `cin.ignore()` to do the cleaning, however, if I used it then I'll have to press enter twice **(in case of inputting `enter` alone)** to enter my input! How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: why do not do if(input == '\n') continue; instead of ignore ?

Comment: You cannot "clear" the input buffer, you have to consume the characters somehow.

Comment: @Pierre: That is wrong. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2979217/341065.

Comment: @GabrieldeGrimouard Because, even if it works, it is still a bit of unnecessary coding and not very efficient. I want a better way, if possible.

Comment: a jmp instruction is way more efficient than use cin.ignore.

Comment: Not reproducible here.  It works just as you wish: hitting enter only once.

Comment: The current code only requires one keypress per prompt (or zero, if you typed more than 100 characters -- to fix this replace `100` by `SIZE_MAX` or some other large number)

Comment: @GabrieldeGrimouard I would love to see that `jmp instruction` if you won't mind. Would you show that using some code?

Comment: @Anich1935 continue is just a jmp instruction to the begening of your while...

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char input;
    while (1)
    {
        cout << "Enter: ";
        cin.get(input);
        cout << input << endl;
        cin.ignore(255, '\n');
        cin.clear();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

you need to clear your cin flags:
    cin.clear();

Comment: What OS are you using by the way?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround in this case might be to use `std::string` and `std::getline`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter: " << std::flush;
        std::string input;

        if(std::getline(std::cin, input) && !input.empty())
        {
            input.front(); // this is your character
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A slight down-side to this is that it allocates memory unnecessarily.   But on the up-side it is simple code.

Answer (score 0):

`std::cin.ignore()` will block until it reads `count` chars or sees its `delimiter`.  There is no reliable way to check if `std::cin` will block before calling an input function.  The only reliable way to prevent it from blocking when `input == '\n'` is to check for that condition before calling `ignore()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    char input;
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Enter: ";
        std::cin.get(input);
        if (input != '\n') {
            // Note: using std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()
            // disables std::istream::ignore's count check entirely
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    }
}
```